# Different css style for each form using simple_form gem

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

Is it possible to have different classes for each simple_form so you can apply different stylesheets??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify class attributes using the html option, thus:

```
simple_form_for object, :html => {:class => "myform"} do |f|
end
```

Comment: Oh, Thanks, I thought that the :html tag was only allowed for input.

Comment: '<%= simple_form_for(@permission), :html => { :class => 'myform' } do |f| %>' this is not working

Comment: You have the brackets wrong, it should be:
<%= simple_form_for(@permission, :html => { :class => 'myform' }) do |f| %>